# initial after last name in citation

Tags: biblatex

How do I change the order of names in citations so that the last name
is first, and any initials to disambiguate between authors with the same
last name follow?

So for this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{cgood1980,
    Author = {Charles Goodwin},
    Journal = {Sociological Inquiry},
    Number = {3-4},
    Pages = {272-302},
    Title = {Restarts, pauses, and the achievement of a state of mutual gaze at turn-beginning},
    Volume = 50,
    Year = 1980,
}
@article{mgood1980,
    Author = {Marjorie Harness Goodwin},
    Journal = {Sociological Inquiry},
    Pages = {303-317},
    Title = {Processes of mutual monitoring implicated in the production of description sequences},
    Volume = 50,
    Year = 1980,
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} 
\begin{document}
\parencite{cgood1980,mgood1980}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

instead of `(C. Goodwin 1980; M. H. Goodwin 1980)` I want
`(Goodwin, C. 1980; Goodwin, M. H. 1980)`. I feel sure the solution must be simple, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no simple option for that. But the changes required are straightforward. You just need to replace all `given-family`s in the definition of `labelname` by `family-given`

```
\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{%
  \ifcase\value{uniquename}%
    \usebibmacro{name:family}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
  \or
    \ifuseprefix
      {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
        {\namepartfamily}
        {\namepartgiveni}
        {\namepartprefix}
        {\namepartsuffixi}}
      {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
        {\namepartfamily}
        {\namepartgiveni}
        {\namepartprefixi}
        {\namepartsuffixi}}%
  \or
    \usebibmacro{name:family-given}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
  \fi
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}
```

That's it.